# Ajax - two URLs for two different target divs

Tags: php, ajax, serialization

My ajax function send the form data to a **db_query.php** then display the result in **'#result'**

```
function submitForm1() {
var form1 = document.myform1;
var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize();
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'db_query.php',
cache: false,
data: dataString1,
success: function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
}
});
return false;
}
```

For the same form I need to add **db_query1.php** to be returned as result in **'#result1'**

**I should need something like this**

```
url: db_query.ph
success: function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
url: db_query1.ph
success: function(data){
$('#result1').html(data);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No you have to make a second request.

Comment: Like this??

$.ajax({
...
});
$.ajax({
...
});
return false;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes and no on your question:

**Does this work?**

```
url: db_query.php
success: function(data){
$('#result').html(data);
url: db_query1.php
success: function(data){
$('#result1').html(data);
```

**NO**, it won't work because you would have to do two ajax-calls to get two responses...

...**BUT** what you could do is to make a relevant response like an array from the db_query.php so it would result in data.result and data.result1

```
function submitForm1() {
var form1 = document.myform1;
var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'db_query.php',
    cache: false,
    data: dataString1,
    success: function(data){
        $('#result').html(data.result);
        $('#result1').html(data.result1);
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: I will try 2 ajax call then. Display same data in both of 2 divs is not what i need.

Comment: @user2635574 - you don't have to display same data in both divs, but you could always return data from ONE php-file with one ajax-call. If you like more info, please tell :-)

Comment: ok as you are so kind I will try to add more info I need to display the following in div nr.2
'.mysql_num_rows($result).'

Comment: @user2635574 - provide the code from db_query.php and db_query1.php and I could give it a try :-) (update your question)